# Display iterate bean value in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, javabeans

```
<logic:iterate id="requirement" name="requirementList" indexId="reqNumber">
        <a href="#" onClick="editItem('<%=requirement.service.description%>')">Edit</a>
</logic:iterate>
```

As you can see, my intention is to populate edit links with a variety of values that are drawn from a list.  The "requirement" bean object displays fine with  but I'm not sure how to get the value in JSP which would be much more useful when populating the javascript method calls.

Edit: Using Struts 1.x

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I don't understand your question. Which "value" are you talking about? What do you want to do, and what difficulties do you have?

Comment: Also, why don't you use JSP EL and the JSTL? Struts has been recommending to use it over logic tags for years.

Comment: Our code practice is to use the logic tags.  Same with the IDE (JDeveloper).

Comment: The "requirement" object, which has values such as id, name, type, etc.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to use the Requirement Java object inside your JavaScript code?

Comment: Close, the requirement object values such as id, name, type passed to a javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use jsp to retrieve that one, that will be a pain in the ass like this.

```
((Requirment)pageContext.getAttribute("requirement")).getService().getDesciption();
```

If you use EL like some other suggested

```
${requirement.service.description}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it a little simpler:

I cast the object "requirement" to an actual requirement object in JSP then used that object to return the values I needed.  The problem was mainly that the iterate object was generic and needed to be casted in order to access the method calls.

Requirement req = (Requirement) requirement;
req.getId();
req.getName();
req.getType();

etc. etc....